# Docker, script seems to build and run properly, but cant connect on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

I am new to using Docker, and I am trying to get a simple React app to work in Docker.

This is my file organization

```
/project-files
Dockerfile
../client
```

Inside client is a basic React app and this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.8.0-stretch
WORKDIR /client
COPY /client/package.json ./client/package.json
RUN npm install 
COPY /client /client
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I run the following commands from :

```
docker build -t test .\project-files\
```

And it seems to build correctly. Then I run

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 test
```

And it seems to compile correctly. I get all the messages and warnings that you would see in a React app

```
> client@0.1.0 start /client
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /client/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Compiled with warnings.

./src/scenes/Home.js
  Line 5:29:  'Card' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

But when I go to http://localhost:8080/ I get a "This page isn’t working, localhost didn’t send any data."

Comment: When you copy `package.json` I think you should simply specify the folder: `COPY /client/package.json ./client`. What are you using to set up the server?

Comment: @Alvaro I don't quite understand what that question means. What server? Also I tried changing it to `COPY /client/package.json ./client`, and nothing changed.

Comment: I mean the tool that is running the app server (webpack dev server, nodemon, pm2, etc.).

Comment: @Alvaro I used create-react-app, which uses webpack I believe, but I made no modifications or changes using webpack.

Comment: I haven't used create-react-app so I can't tell for sure, but isn't it using the port 3000 by default (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-start-or-yarn-start))?

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks! This is the reason why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your Dockerfile contents and managed to get it to run (with create-react-app):

```
FROM node:13.8.0-stretch
WORKDIR /client
COPY ./client/package.json /client/package.json
RUN npm install 
COPY ./client /client
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I made the following changes:

1. I changed some of the paths - I'm not entirely sure on your file structure but it didn't seem right to me. I changed both your COPY lines.
2. I change the exposed port from `8080` to `3000`
3. I ran the following build command `docker build -t test .` when in the same directory as the Dockerfile
4. I used 3000 in the run command `docker run -p 3000:3000 test`

When I visited http://localhost:3000/ it showed my app.

In summary – I think it was your COPY paths and your EXPOSEd port

---

My file structure:

```
.
├── _Dockerfile
├── _client
|   ├── package.json
|   ├── package-lock.json
|   ├── public
|   └── src
```

Comment: Thanks so much, appreciate the answer! Changing the port from 8080 to 3000 fixed it.